# How to get all the li in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<ul id="tab">
  <li onclick="clicker()" class="li01">one test</li>
  <li onclick="clicker()" class="li02">two test</li>
  <li onclick="clicker()" class="li03">three test</li>
  <div class="web_clear"></div>
</ul>
<div class="web_index">
  content....
</div>
```

I used `document.getElementsByTagName("ul").childNodes;` to get all the `li`. But it doesn't work.

Comment: try this `document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].childNodes`

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("li")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `id`

```
document.getElemensById("tab").childNodes;
```

Or if its the only `ul` then

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].childNodes;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = document.getElementById('tab').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("li")
```

this should work it will return an array of elements

Answer (score 1):

You can get a NodeList to iterate through by using getElementsByTagName() , like this:

```
var list_li = document.getElementById("tab").getElementsByTagName("li");
```